# Testing jQTouch Swipe Events on Development machine

Tags: debugging, testing, browser, jqtouch, swipe

I'm currently developing a quicky mobile application using JQTouch - everything is going well but I've got a bit of a debugging issue.

At the moment I'm implementing all the core functionality, so using my development box (Windows, Using Safari to test it) I'd like to ensure that swipes are being handled correctly. However, short of booting up in Mac OS X or hosting it online and running it from my iPhone (may seem like no real trouble - but hey, we're all coders! We all know how comfortable our toolkits/environments are) - is there a way to test swipes "in browser"?

I thought I could simply click and drag to mimic a swipe but that just results in my dragging my image away...!

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

There is no easy way, that I know of, to test iPhone applications (Web app or not) on a non-Mac machine.

Your best bet is probably to run Mac OS X through a virtual machine, e.g. VMWare. Then install XCode, which has an iPhone Simulator. You can get XCode for free after you register yourself as an iPhone developer with Apple.

- [Leopard image for VMWare](http://thepiratebay.org/torrent/4798016/MAC_OS_X_Leopard_10.5.5_VMware_Image)
- [Snow Leopard image for VMWare](http://www.redmondpie.com/how-to-install-os-x-snow-leopard-in-vmware-windows-7-9140301/)

Comment: I have a Mac OS X box I can use if it comes down to it, it's just I'd really like to be able to test out simple things like swiping in browser!

Comment: Personally, I do not trust any third-party iPhone simulator, as they essentially simulate to simulate. Even the iPhone Simulator is not 100% trustful, IMHO, but it does reflect very closely to the actual device.